# SQL pivot on both a value column and a bit column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a `RawDataTable` like this:

| Date | Country | Value | Accurate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | ABW | 4 | true |
| 2001 | ABW | 9 | true |
| 2002 | ABW | 8 | true |
| 2000 | GBR | 1 | false |
| 2001 | GBR | 3 | true |
| 2002 | GBR | 4 | false |

I'm pivoting it in SQL Server to get the following format:

| Date | ABW | GBR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | 4 | 1 |
| 2001 | 9 | 3 |
| 2002 | 8 | 4 |

But I'm hoping to include the `Accurate` column in the return too, maybe spread out so that each country also has its own `Accurate` column, like this:

| Date | ABW | GBR | ABW Accurate | GBR Accurate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | 4 | 1 | true | false |
| 2001 | 9 | 3 | true | true |
| 2002 | 8 | 4 | true | false |

I'm using the query below to pivot it so far, but have literally no idea if what I want to do is possible nor where to begin on modifying the query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         [Date],
         [Country],
         [Value]
     FROM 
         RawDataTable) CountryVals
PIVOT 
    (SUM([Value])
         FOR [Country] IN ([ABW], [GBR])
    ) AS PivotTable
```

I got as far as including `Accurate` as the fourth column in the first `select`. I tried joining another pivot to the end of the query but that didn't work, I tried adding that col in the pivot select... and actually I couldn't even get a pivot to work for `Accurate` anyway because it's a `bit` type and not a `decimal` e.g. so not sure what to use in place of SUM

Answer (score 2):

I usually find it a lot easier to work with a conditional case expression for simple pivoting such as this, you can cut-and-paste repeating columns easily. `Pivot` is just unintuitive syntactic sugar which SQL Server expands internally to case expressions anyway.

```
select date,
    Max(case when country='ABW' then value end) ABW,
    Max(case when country='GBR' then value end) GBR,
    Max(case when country='ABW' then accurate end) ABWAccurate,
    Max(case when country='GBR' then accurate end) GBRAccurate
from t
group by date
```

Comment: It's actually a dynamic statement that's built so it's really easy to just sub in the list of countries in one place on a pivot, but I guess I can still create the above format dynamically too - and yeah, the way it's written with case statements makes a lot more sense to my programmer head.

Comment: Yes absolutely, I use dynamic pivots a lot for reporting, they are also easier to construct like this, at least that's what I find.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for you using pivot:

And here is sqlfiddle: [multipivot](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/58959/8)

```
;WITH PIV1 AS
(
  SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT    
        [Date],
        [Country],
        [Value]
      FROM RawDataTable
    ) CountryVals
    PIVOT (
      SUM([Value])
      FOR [Country]
      IN ([ABW],[GBR])
    ) AS PivotTable
  ), PIV2 AS
  (
    SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT    
        [Date],
        [Country],
        [Accurate]
      FROM RawDataTable
    ) CountryVals
    PIVOT (
      MAX([Accurate])
      FOR [Country]
      IN ([ABW],[GBR])
    ) AS PivotTable
  )
  
  SELECT PIV1.Date, PIV1.ABW, PIV1.GBR, PIV2.ABW AS [ABW Accurate] , PIV2.GBR [GBR Accurate]
  FROM PIV1 INNER JOIN PIV2 ON PIV1.[Date] = PIV2.[Date]
```